# Simulate simple non-homogeneous Poisson proces

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, simulation

Consider a Poisson process whose conditional intensity is

$$\lambda(t) = \alpha e^{-t}$$

starting at time $t=0$ for some parameter $\alpha>0$.

I would like to simulate arrival/event/failure times as efficiently as possible. (I am not sure what the standard term is for the times you get from a Poisson process.) Is there a fast way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *"Amusing" downvote to an otherwise perfectly valid answer.*

If one knows how to simulate a homogenous Poisson process $(N(t))$ with intensity $\alpha$ on the time interval $[0,1]$, one can then consider the process $(X(t))$ defined, for every $t\geqslant0$, by $$X(t)=N(1-\mathrm e^{-t}).$$

Comment: Could you explain in procedural terms what you have in mind please?  I can indeed simply simulate a homogeneous Poisson process.    This is straightforward to do in a sequential fashion using the fact that the time to the next arrival follows an exponential distribution.

Comment: This IS already "explain[ed] in procedural terms", no?

Comment: Sorry if I am being slow.  I would like to write code to do this simulation and I can't see yet how to do it.  Do I simulate times from some homogeneous Poisson process and them transform those times to get the times from my non-homogeneous one?

Comment: Yes--as is written explicitely in my answer.